# get data to windows mobile app from a web API

Tags: windows, mobile, asp.net-web-api

I want to get specific data from a action in a webAPI controller to my windows mobile app .here is my webAPI action;

```
 // GET: api/Customer/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetValidCustomer(string username,string password)
        {

            var customer = (from cust in db.Customers
                            where cust.CustomerName == username && cust.CustomerPw == password
                            select cust).ToList();

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(customer);
            }

        }
```

I have tried to consume that action as follows,but the windows emulator starts to freeze when I use that method.

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> isValidUser(string username,string password)
        {
            try
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2335");
                    var url = "api/Customer?username="+username+"&password="+password;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {                          

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How long does it freeze for? Are you sure it's not just waiting to try and connect to your localhost? Have you put breakpoints in the action? Does it even get hit?

Comment: yes. i also tried using a break point ,but finally problem was the return value from the web API does not match with the actual return type of the action. How ever i was able to fix it. Thank you very much for your great support.